# Is there a word for "querulism"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I find I often need a word such as this. Some people are just relentless querulants and I want to be able to refer to that aspect of them, e.g. *"John's relentless querulism"*. Doesn't seem like that's a real word though...

[Wikipedia on Querulant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querulant)

Thanks

Comment: I don't recognise your word *querulant*, and it's not in OED, so could you explain where you got it from, and what you want it to mean? *Querulous* mean *having a complaining nature*, from which the noun form is *querulation*. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Already added the Wikipedia link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FumbleFingers is right in saying that *querulant* is not in the OED, but *querulist*, 'A person who complains, a complainer', is. The corresponding noun, also in the OED, is *querulousness*, meaning ‘The state or condition of being querulous’ and it's probably the word you're looking for. However, you may want to be sure your intended readers will know what these words mean before using them.

Comment: Outside of formal usage (in legal, psychiatric contexts, etc.) I think people would normally just say *complaining* or (much more likely for me) **carping** anyway.

Comment: The OED may say *querulist* is a word, while *querulant* isn't, but [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=querulousness%2Cquerulant%2Cquerulantism%2C+querulist&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) says the opposite.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Leafing through NGram instances of *querulant* over the past 40 years, I see less than a dozen that are actually in *English* publications (invariably in a psychiatry context). All results after the first page or two seem to be in German publications.

Answer (score 3):

As Barrie says, *querulousness* (or *querulation*) are the actual derived terms.

But in practice most people would speak of **John's [constant carping](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22his%20adopted%20language%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22constant%20carping%22&oq=%22constant%20carping%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...282560l287047l4l287621l18l18l0l0l0l0l128l1021l17j1l18l0.frgbld.&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=91f800d42349df6a&biw=1289&bih=902)**.